# azure vhd mount exception ERROR_HTTPS_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, blob, vhd

I have uploaded a VHD using Cloud storage studio. It gave a https based blob URL. On windows azure, when I try to mount that VHD using drive.Mount method, I get following exception:

ERROR_HTTPS_NOT_SUPPORTED

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was issue with uploading Cloud Storage Studio. When one upload the vhd using https, it gives URL of https, and when some upload vhd using http it gives URL of http. I uploaded the vhd using http and problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you give it an http based url? According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2010/04/07/using-windows-azure-drive-part-2-modifying-my-application-to-use-the-drive.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) https is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP. **Azure drive does not support HTTPS**